# how to take a value in Session id

Tags: php

my code is
in line no 13, `starttimer.php?testid=$row[0]`, I want to assign the value of `$row[0]` in a session `testid`. Help me to do this.(database table is `rec_test` and column is `pid`)

```
<?php
extract($_GET);
$rs=mysql_query("select * from rec_test");
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)<1)
{
echo "<br><br><h2 class=head1> No Quiz available </h2>";
exit;
}
echo "<h2 class=head1> Select Quiz Name to Give Quiz </h2>";
echo "<table align=center>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($rs))
{
echo "<tr><td align=center ><a href=starttimer.php?testid=$row[0]<h3><font color=red>$row[1]</font></h3></a></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td> &nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Anything wrong with `$_SESSION['testid'] = $row[0]`?

Comment: you want to store session testid inside while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understood your question, but I guess you want to assign the column `pid` to the link.

First thing to do is not to use a generic '`*`' when queering the database, second use mysql_fetch_assoc to get an associative array back.

```
<?php
extract($_GET);
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT pid, name FROM rec_test");
if ( mysql_num_rows($rs) < 1 )
{
    echo "<br><br><h2 class=head1> No Quiz available </h2>";
    exit;
}
echo "<h2 class=head1> Select Quiz Name to Give Quiz </h2>";
echo "<table align=center>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    echo '<tr>'
        .'<td align="center" >'
         .'<a href="starttimer.php?testid='.$row['pid'].'">'
          .'<h3><font color="red">'.$row['name'].'</font></h3>'
         .'</a>'
        .'</td>'
        .'</tr>';
    echo "<tr><td> &nbsp;</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Also consider switching to Mysqli or PDO as the **mysql extension is depracated** and dropped all together starting with PHP 5.5.

And please don't use extract on unsecure data, as the PHP manual states:
Warning

> Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (i.e. $_GET,
>   $_FILES, etc.). If you do, for example if you want to run old code
>   that relies on register_globals temporarily, make sure you use one of
>   the non-overwriting flags values such as EXTR_SKIP and be aware that
>   you should extract in the same order that's defined in variables_order
>   within the php.ini.